# lose vim colorscheme in tmux mode

Tags: macos, vim, tmux, iterm

I'm running iterm2 and when I'm in tmux mode the colorscheme I have set in vim does not show up. Only the color scheme I've set in iterm. If I run vim from shell the colorscheme appears correct - its only when I'm in tmux mode.

I've tried setting `:colorscheme molokai` when in vim (see screenshot below) and it doesn't change - again, the default colorscheme for iterm2 remains.

Am I missing some setting to iterm or tmux.conf? My dotfles are up on github here.

Comment: What happens when you do `$ tmux -2`?

Comment: That was totally it. What's the -2 flag?

Comment: It forces tmux to work with 256 colors.

Comment: @romainl something good happens :)

Answer (score 284, accepted):

I had the same problem. Only difference was I am using `solarize` rather then `molokai`.

To fix the issue, I have set up an alias in `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias tmux="TERM=screen-256color-bce tmux"
```

And set up the `default-terminal` option in `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm"
```

Lastly, do `$ source ~/.bashrc` to load new alias.

Comment: I use this instead of `tmux -2` as this is more verbose.

Comment: Personally I had to use `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` to work rather than `xterm` on OS X, sshed into an Ubuntu box. I referred to this site: http://rhnh.net/2011/08/20/vim-and-tmux-on-osx

Comment: The alias here doesn't make sense: it's pretending to tmux that it's running inside screen or tmux, which is hardly ever the case. To tell tmux to assume that the terminal it's running in supports 256 colors, run `tmux -2` or `tmux -2 attach` (tmux decides each time you attach a new or existing session to a terminal). A sensible alias would be `alias tmux='tmux -2'`. See also [tmux, TERM and 256 colours support](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118806/tmux-term-and-256-colours-support)

Comment: I read in some other answer (couldn't find the reference) that it was not a good practice to force the TERM, though I don't know for sure. Since the `tmux -2` option with the `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` worked for me, that will be my choice. But thanks anyway!

Comment: If the `.tmux.conf` setting doesn't appear to be taking effect, close ***all*** tmux processes and restart. You can just do `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` without setting any alias in `.bashrc`. I think people are doing workarounds like the environment variable alias because they aren't closing all tmux processes after configuring `.tmux.conf`.

Comment: I ended up exporting `TERM` as `xterm-256color` and adding `set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"` to my tmux config. In my OS X terminal profile I ensured that the terminal was declared as `xterm-256color` as well. I ensured that my terminal profile was set to the same TERM type. This works preserves my fish shell and vim themes.

Comment: To confirm, just adding `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` to `.tmux.conf`worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: The `default-terminal` here didn't help me, vim kept starting up with weird bindings (i.e. Home/End keys switching to insert mode and inserting F and H plus newline).
I set an alias in my .bashrc instead: `alias vim='TERM=xterm vim'`

Comment: This worked perfectly on vim but for some reasons started to be messed up on neovim, especially since all the comment-outs now have background highlight...

Comment: @seyeong-jeong Can you kindly edit the answer to include [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158508/lose-vim-colorscheme-in-tmux-mode#comment42029406_10264470)? Would've saved me some time if I saw this earlier. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using CentOS 8 and for me, the right configuration was `set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"` in my `~/.tmux.conf`. I also didn't need to make any changes to my `.bashrc` file for it to work.

Comment: What do I do if this, nor any other the other answers work.

Comment: In my case I would get
`missing or unsuitable terminal: screen-256color-bce` when doing that. I solved it by using `alias tmux="TERM=xterm-256color tmux"` instead.

Comment: Why would you first specify one TERM when launching tmux and then another in the configuration. Default-terminal should be a variant of screen or tmux to work correctly

Answer (score 121):

I tried all the solutions above and what finally worked for me is putting the following lines in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```

Comment: I am using tmux via SSH and this is also what worked for me even though I am not using xterm, just regular SSH.

Comment: I wasn't using it over ssh and this was the only answer that worked for me. Local iTerm session in OSX 10.9.5.

Comment: This works for me (MacOS Mojave + iTerm2/Alacritty), thanks

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Indeed, this is the correct solution, particularly on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: ⚠️ See @Chev 's answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25940093/931156

Comment: This worked for me, using iTerm2 on macOS Catalina.

Comment: Something recently broke my vim color scheme on a WSL2 installation of Ubuntu on WIndows 11, running inside Windows Terminal. This was the correct fix.

Comment: This pretends your terminal emulator is no longer a tmux or screen instead of actually solving the problem. From the tmux manual "For *tmux* to work correctly this **must** be set to 'screen', 'tmux' or derivative of them". At least change it to `screen.xterm-256color`

Answer (score 81):

As @romainl mentions above, I needed to force tmux to use 256 colors by adding the `-2` flag:

```
$ tmux -2
```

I added `alias tmux='tmux -2'` to my bash_profile, so, I don't forget :)

Comment: Actually, it's not mandatory at all: I don't use `-2` but I have 256 colors working in Vim in tmux.

Comment: @romainl It's necessary if tmux doesn't detect your terminal as having 256 colors, which is fairly common.

Comment: @Gilles, Vim doesn't detect that the terminal supports 256 colors because tmux's default `TERM` is `screen`. `-2` doesn't change `TERM` and doesn't change anything color-related to what info Vim gets from its environment: `:echo &t_Co` still returns `8`. With the info it is given, Vim does the right thing. The only things that must be set are 1. your terminal emulator's `TERM` to `xterm-256color` or an equivalent value like `urxvt-unicode-256color` and 2. tmux's default `TERM` with `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`.

Comment: @romainl Most environments have `TERM` set to `xterm`, not `xterm-256color`, hence the need to run `tmux -2` (or `TERM=xterm-256color tmux`, or change the termcap or other ways of accomplishing the same thing).

Comment: @Gilles, the problem is that -2 doesn't accomplish anything that has any impact on Vim's behavior regarding 256 color support because the only thing that matters to Vim is your TERM and that's to be set at your end of the chain: in your terminal emulator. If you SSH through 5 hosts and your terminal is set correctly, Vim launched on the 5th host will see your 256 colors TERM and act accordingly. If you use tmux at any point of the chain -2 will have zero impact on Vim's behavior because all it sees is its environment is limited to 8 colors because of tmux's default TERM: screen, -2 or not.

Comment: @romainl You need to take care of both the outside (`-2` or `TERM=xterm-256color` or setting the `xterm` termcap/terminfo to declare 256 colors) and the inside (`set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` or setting the `screen` termcap/terminfo to declare 256 colors).

Comment: @Gilles, which is almost exactly my point except that -2 is pointless since it's so easy to

Answer (score 38):

I just discovered why I was having a lot of confusion. I, like others here, was having a difficult time getting the default-terminal setting to take effect. I remembered that I had a tmux session in the background. I re-attached my session, closed out my processes, and closed ALL tmux processes. The next time I restarted tmux the default-terminal setting in `.tmux.conf` began to take effect. I don't know if others are doing this as well but I recommend closing all tmux processes before modifying the `.tmux.conf` file.

I got my setup to work on my local machine (OSX 10.9.5 with iTerm2) without any modification to `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. All I did was add the line `set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"` to `~/.tmux.conf` and restarted all tmux processes.

I got my remote setup (ssh to Ubuntu 14.04) to work exactly the same way without any modifications to `.bashrc`. I simply added `set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"` to `~/.tmux.conf` on my remote machine and restarted all remote tmux processes.

You can test what Vim is seeing by doing `echo $TERM` from within a tmux session. It kept saying `screen` as the value until I restarted all tmux processes, at which point it reflected `xterm-256color` as expected.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've confirmed on several more operating systems since this post, closing all processes and setting the `default-terminal` option in `.tmux.conf` has worked 100% of the time so far.

Comment: me too! i would have spent less time on this if this answer were farther up.

Answer (score 21):

So this a bit on the stale side, but it's might be worth mentioning that using screen will often break the Home and End keys. Using

```
export TERM="xterm-256color"
```

it should keep the functionality of these and allow the color scheme (or powerline) to work fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I didn't know that. It still seems to work for Debian derv from what I've seen so far. In my defence the post was in reference to OSX.

Comment: tmux 1.9a, OSX 10.9.2, iTerm2 Build 1.0.0.20130622

export TERM="xterm-256color" in .bash_profile, then set iterm to xterm-256-color worked for me. No need to set any tmux configuration.

Answer (score 19):

I needed vim to display correctly with tmux in terminal on ubuntu and cygwin/mintty on windows. I got it to work by combining the answers like this.

In .bashrc:

```
alias tmux="tmux -2"
```

In .vimrc:

```
" use 256 colors in terminal
if !has("gui_running")
    set t_Co=256
    set term=screen-256color
endif

" fix cursor display in cygwin
if has("win32unix")
    let &t_ti.="\e[1 q"
    let &t_SI.="\e[5 q"
    let &t_EI.="\e[1 q"
    let &t_te.="\e[0 q"
endif
```

based on answers from this question, [this Vim wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim) and [this block cursor question](https://superuser.com/questions/634326/how-can-i-get-a-block-cursor-in-vim-in-the-cygwin-terminal)

Comment: I had the issue with mintty, and adding the vim configuration fixed it for me. I didn't even need to do the `tmux` alias.

Comment: @trigoman , same for me too, i just had to update the .vimrc.

Comment: I tried all of the previous suggestions.  Just added ```set t_Co=256``` to .vimrc and it was fixed.  I didn't need to create a ```tmux``` alias.

Answer (score 15):

In case anyone needs 24-bit color support:

Tmux supports 24-bit color as of version 2.2. If your terminal supports 24-bit color, add your terminal to the terminal-overrides setting. For example,

```
set -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"
```

My environment checklist:

- macOS Sierra 10.12.3
- iTerm2 3.0.14 (Report Terminal Type is `xterm-256color`)
- neovim 0.1.7 (Enable 24-bit color by adding: `xterm-256color` to `.vimrc`)
- tmux 2.3 (Add `set -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"` to `.tmux.conf`)

Nothing else I need to add in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`.

Hope this could help.

Comment: only thing that worked for me. what exactly does this do?

Comment: It enables true color support. The current recommendations have changed for 3.2 (`set -as terminal-features ",xterm-256:RGB"`) https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-rgb-colour

Answer (score 15):

Since this is the first result on Google and since none of the above helped..wanted to post this so that someone might find it helpful

in `.vimrc`:

```
set background=dark
set t_Co=256
```

HTH

Comment: Have tested these two lines, and they work well for my Vim on WSL-Windows10.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked on Ubuntu 18 with gnome-terminal

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me on RedHat using xterm. Thanks!

Comment: worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 with gnome

Answer (score 11):

I have tried all of the instructions above, and I found out the most important thing is I have to explicitly add the following line in my .bashrc file.

```
export TERM=screen-256color
```

I don't know why alias tmux="TERM=screen-256color-bce tmux" doesn't work out.
I use Sierra 10.12.1.

Comment: This is what worked for me. Just plain export of TERM. +1

Comment: don't set the value of TERM in .bashrc or similar

Answer (score 9):

Just had to deal with this problem, and although all previously posted answers were helpful, they did not solve the issue in my case.

My problem was fixed by **removing** the following line in my `.vimrc`:

```
set termguicolors
```

which was redondant with another instruction anyway.

Now, with the following line found in previous anwsers in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
export TERM="screen-256color"
```

all is nice and colorful.

Comment: Upvoted. All answers are wrong. You should set tmux terminal to `tmux-256color` which is most accurate.

Comment: this just disables 24-bit color in vim

Answer (score 6):

I'm using gnome terminal and this solved the problem, but (0) don't forget to:

```
killall tmux
```

(1) Edit .tmux.conf

```
# 24 bit color
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
set -ga terminal-overrides ",*256col*:Tc"
```

(2) Edit: .vimrc

```
" Enable true color
if exists('+termguicolors')
  let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
  let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
  set termguicolors
endif
```

Solution posted by rinetd on tmux repo issue:
https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1246

Answer (score 5):

Adding the following line in .tmux.conf worked for me with macOS Sierra 10.12.6,

set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

Comment: Same here. Thank you @waffl for finding this solution!

Answer (score 4):

If you find yourself in the same sitation as me, that none of the above worked.. try this:

in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm"
```

in bash config (maybe `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`):

```
alias tmux="tmux -2"
```

and then run:

```
killall tmux
```

and then relaunch tmux

Answer (score 3):

If you use `tmuxinator` or `mux`, you will need to add these in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
alias tmux='TERM=screen-256color tmux -2'
alias tmuxinator='TERM=screen-256color tmuxinator'
alias mux='TERM=screen-256color mux'
```

These forces to use 256-color in terminal.

Then `tmux`, `tmuxinator` and `mux` command will all work.

Answer (score 3):

I've removed the line `set termguicolors`, but it doesn't work.
Setting `set notermguicolors` instead in the `.vimrc` works.

Answer (score 2):

From the tmux man page, adding flag as following:

```
tmux -2
```

This `-2` flag forces tmux to run on 256-color mode.

This works for me

Answer (score 2):

In order to set up correct color and to get rid of rendering issue in both Ubuntu and Mac:

[check this](https://superuser.com/questions/399296/256-color-support-for-vim-background-in-tmux/1021078#1021078)

Answer (score 2):

Using these two lines in my .tmux.conf worked for me, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with Alacritty.

```
set  -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
set -ag terminal-overrides ",alacritty:RGB"
```

Found them in an issue on alacitty's repo, in the comment provided by YodaEmbedding:

https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/109

Comment: This works great for `tmux/neovim/alacritty`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have much luck trying to export a different `TERM` or set default-terminal in my `.tmux.conf`.

My solution for fixing vim colors within tmux was adding this line to `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm:colors=88'
```

I'm not sure why this override was needed given that my `TERM=xterm` and I have iTerm set to xterm as well, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu bionic 18.04.4 LTS and tmux 2.6.
I have the same issue and it can be resolved by simply adding this into .bashrc

```
export TERM=screen-256color
```

And ofcourse don't forget to source it.
    `source ~/.bashrc`

Or just restart your teminal

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming** that you already have vim colors matching with your terminal:

1. Kill all tmux sessions running `tmux kill-server`
2. Create a user configuration file for tmux in `~/.tmux.conf`
3. Add to the `.tmux.conf` the following lines:
   `set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"`
   `set -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-termite:Tc"`
4. Run in your command line `echo $TERM`
5. Replace `xterm-termite` with the output returned by `echo $TERM`

Answer (score 1):

*ENV*:

Fedora 29 workstation x86_64, GNOME Terminal 3.30.1

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Mar  8 2019 09:25:44)

GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

tmux 2.7

vim is using solarized scheme.

`.vimrc`

```
...
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
let g:solarized_termtrans=1

syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
...
```

The value of `$TERM` in bash is:

```sh
[u@loc ~]$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
[u@loc ~]$ tput colors
256
```

---

**Mehthod 1**: works.

Check `$TERM` value inside tmux session. Get

```sh
[u@loc ~]$ echo $TERM
screen
[u@loc ~]$ tput colors
8
```

So, just set `export TERM=screen-256color` inside tmux session. This method only works in the current pane of the session.

---

**Method 2**: works.

Create `~/.tmux.conf` file and add `set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"` to the file.

or Just run `echo "set -g default-terminal \"tmux-256color\"" > ~/.tmux.conf`

Then kill all tmux sessions.

Start a new session and check the `$TERM` value inside tmux session. Get

```sh
[u@loc ~]$ echo $TERM
tmux-256color
[u@loc ~]$ tput colors
256
```

And vim colorized scheme works fine for all pane and all tmux sessions.

I also tried `xterm-256color` and `screen-256color` in `~/.tmux.conf`. They all work fine for colorizing the vim scheme.

By the way, I don't have any configurations being related to this setting in my `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` and `~/.vimrc`.

See also https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-a-256-colour-terminal, https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#why-do-you-use-the-screen-terminal-description-inside-tmux

Other useful talks are [Vim color scheme changes in tmux #699](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/699), [256-color-support-for-vim-background-in-tmux](https://superuser.com/questions/399296/256-color-support-for-vim-background-in-tmux/1021078#1021078), [getting-256-colors-to-work-in-tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/getting-256-colors-to-work-in-tmux), [tmux-term-and-256-colours-support](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118806/tmux-term-and-256-colours-support/118903#118903)

Answer (score 1):

Inside Vim you can check the term variable:

:set term?

Do this inside tmux and outside, and compare them.
Here I put this line inside .vimrc to solve the problem:

set term=xterm-256color

And now, both inside and outside tmux, the term variable is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I use fedora 34.

I add this to .tmux.conf file

`set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"`

Then add this to .vimrc

```
set background=dark
set t_Co=256
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to make tmux using the same terminal and 24 bit color as your terminal so that they will look the same.

Run `echo $TERM` and `echo $TERMCOLOR` in iTerm we get:
`xterm-256color`  and `truecolor`.

Run `echo $TERM` and `echo $TERMCOLOR` in tmux we get:
`screen-256color`  and blank.

To make them the same, just add 2 lines into `~/.tmux.conf`:

1. `set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"` to use xterm
2. `set -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"` to use true color
3. you must run `tmux kill-server` to restart tmux for the change to take effect
4. Btw, your vim must be using true colors also. `set termguicolors` in `.vimrc` will make your vim colors same as terminal. Put in this line to your `~/.vimrc` if you are having disparities between vim and terminal colorscheme.

This should do it. Of course your tmux version should support true color first.

Answer (score 0):

You likely experiencing one of two problems, and possibly both at the same time.

#### default-terminal

1. The value of `$TERM` in `tmux` doesn't support color, or not the colors you need. Perhaps it's `screen`, which is monochrome.

Change this by modifying the `default-terminal`. Possibly using

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
```

or `screen.xterm-256color`, `screen-256color` etc.

#### set termguicolors

2. The vim color settings are incompatible with the terminal and/or tmux.

In order to use truecolor in vim you usually

```
set termguicolors
```

but this only works nicely with `xterm*`. Use this in your `.vimrc` to play nicely with `xterm`, as well as other `screen`, `tmux` variants.

```
if !has('gui_running') && &term =~ '\%(screen\|tmux\)'
  let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
  let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
endif
set termguicolors
```

The check in term should be a bit more elaborate, to actually match variants with color but this should work for most setups.

##### Alternative approaches

- Pretend `tmux` is `xterm`, it's not. Both top answers suggest this approach but it's stated in the manual

> For tmux to work correctly, this must be set to ‘screen’, ‘tmux’ or a derivative of them.

- Disable vims truecolor support. This shouldn't be needed but sure, you can disable 24-bit color support and just use 256 colors.