# Vim 256 colour strange behaviour with tmux

Tags: vim, tmux, 256color

Just an interesting little problem I've got going on with terminals. I'm using vim inside of gnome-terminal. I like to have 256 colours so I don't have to use gVIM.

My relevant .zshrc settings are:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

My relevant .vimrc settings are:

```
if $COLORTERM == 'gnome-terminal'
  set t_Co=256
endif
```

You'll notice from this showterm what the problem is:
http://showterm.io/06460aeb043cac4bd0256

I'm getting a weird background colour with the tmux vim. Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Does the answer here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158508/lose-vim-colorscheme-in-tmux-mode?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

This is just a quick investigation.

1. after execute *tmux* inside *gnome-termnial*, "COLORTERM" will be overwritten. That means $COLORTERM is NULL inside tmux.

The flow of these variables.

1. gnome-terminal starts and load your .zshrc. (TERM=xterm-256color COLORTERM = gnome-terminal)
2. tmux starts. (it overwrite COLORTERM, load its config "default-terminal" as the value of TERM)
3. tmux load .zshrc (TERM is rewritten to "xterm-256color")
4. Now => TERM = "xterm-256color" COLORTERM = ""
5. vim starts => (besides your .vimrc config, t_Co is set to 256 if the term is 256 color)

The problem is that tmux support 256 color correctly only if TERM="screen-256color" instead of "xterm-256color".

Below is a solution:

First, add this to your .zshrc(I use bash syntax):

```
if [[ $COLORTERM == 'gnome-terminal" ]]; then
            export TERM="xterm-256color"
fi
```

Second, add this to your "~/.tmux.conf":

```
set -g default-terminal screen-256color
```

Last, vim settings is not needed.

Any further questions, please comment.

Comment: Tmux doesn't overwrite $COLORTERM. Inside tmux, $COLORTERM still equals 'gnome-terminal'. The problem is that inside tmux, $TERM is 'xterm-256color', when it needs to be 'screen-256color'. Not sure why the .tmux.conf isn't overriding it.

Comment: Well, my tmux overwrites it in my experiment, thanks for point this out. For the second, I believe it is because tmux load .tmux.conf first and then load .zshrc, so any further configuration in .zshrc will be finally set.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.  This has worked for me:

---

## `.tmux.conf`

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

---

Also, remove the old `term` value for `.vimrc`

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to overwrite the 'term' setting inside the vimrc. Vim can figure it out by itself from the $TERM variable.