# Tmux does not show Vim colors properly (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: vim, ubuntu-14.04, tmux, gnome-terminal

Searching around, I found that it might be a problem with Tmux detecting the correct terminal mode, so I placed this in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Together with `alias tmux="tmux -2"` it makes some colorschemes work (`badwolf` for example), but not all of them (doesn't work for `solarized`, `vividchalk` and `base16` for example). Since I wanted at least `solarized`, I installed it to gnome-terminal and to Vim. Colors show properly out of Tmux, but not in Tmux. I also set `t_Co=256` (in Vim) but without success.

According to [Tmux faq](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/master/tree/FAQ), there is nothing wrong with my configuration, but yet I can't get it to display properly. Any idea?

### Update

To give a better understanding of the problem, below are some images.

First, Gvim (left) and Vim (right, in gnome-terminal):
[image: GVim | Vim]

Second, Vim (left, in gnome-terminal), Vim with tmux (right, also in gnome-terminal):
[image: Vim | Vim with Tmux]

Credits: the code is from [Princeton Algorithms course](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/Merge.java) (authors: Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne).

Comment: Can you add screenshots of what you want and what you get? Note that you should leave your terminal at 8/16 colors to make the best use of the over-engineered crap that is solarized.

Comment: Updated! I'm not sure, but solarized should work even with 256 colors, no?

Answer (score 6):

There are some steps required to solve this problem:

1. Install the `solarized` theme for `gnome-terminal`, [found here](https://github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized).
2. Install the `solarized` theme for Vim ([found here](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized)).
3. Create an alias for the `tmux` command or set the TERM variable as mentioned in **ianks** answer (in your `.bashrc`):

   `alias tmux="TERM=screen-256color-bce tmux"`
4. Include the following line in your `.tmux.conf`:

   `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`

I needed all these 4 steps to make my terminal colors show solarized. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10264470/1814970) provides some other alternatives in case this doesn't work. One particular comment in that post helped the most, pointing to [this resource](http://rhnh.net/2011/08/20/vim-and-tmux-on-osx).

It turns out that without setting the TERM variable, if you `echo $TERM` you see exactly what Tmux FAQ said you should (`screen-256color`), but you don't get the correct colors, don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this to your .(*)shrc?

```
export TERM=screen-256color-bce
```

Back when I used gnome terminal this worked for me, but don't ask me why :)

Comment: Thanks! That was part of the answer :)