# Vim loses colorscheme when launched from tmux

Tags: vim, command-line, tmux, color-scheme

When I launch vim from gnome terminal the colorscheme and the powerline colors are displayed correctly. However when I launch tmux and then launch vim within tmux the colorscheme and the powerline color are somewhat disabled. I've tried many things from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158508/lose-vim-colorscheme-in-tmux-mode) thread but nothing seems to work for me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Here are some pictures that can help you understand my problem:

Vim launched within tmux. The instruction I used to launch tmux was: $ tmux
[image: Vim within tmux]

Vim launched within tmux. The instruction I used to launch tmux was: $ tmux -2
[image: Vim within tmux]

Keep in mind that my .vimrc file contains the `set t_Co=256` instruction.
Thank you.

**EDIT 1**: I have this `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` in my ~/.tmux.conf file as well.

**EDIT 2**: Information about my system:

- OS: Arch Linux
- Terminal: Gnome-terminal
- Vim version:
  VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Mar  6 2017 14:13:23)
  Included patches: 1-427 Compiled by Arch Linux
- Tmux version: tmux 2.3

Comment: I have this in by .tmux.conf `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`  Could you try adding that?

Comment: @sudobangbang I already have this in my ~/.tmux.conf file.