# VIM not using proper colorscheme in tmux

Tags: vim, tmux, vim-plugin

I have referred to this question and I tried many of the changes suggested and it worked for a moment. I updated my Ubuntu machine to latest version and it broke my tmux.
[lose vim colorscheme in tmux mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158508/lose-vim-colorscheme-in-tmux-mode)

Currently everything works perfectly outside of tmux but the vim in tmux is having problems.

My vimrc :

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'arcticicestudio/nord-vim'
Plug 'fatih/vim-go', { 'do': ':GoUpdateBinaries' }
call plug#end()

set termguicolors
set hlsearch
syntax on
colorscheme nord
```

I have set these 2 variables in my bashrc

```
export TERM="xterm-256color"
alias tmux='tmux -2'
```

One ans suggested to add this `set -g default-terminal "xterm"` in tmux.conf but adding this loses all the colors in my tmux.

I am using this https://github.com/lemnos/theme.sh for setting colorscheme of my terminal.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recently had this problem myself. When comparing your config files to mine, I have a few more lines than you.

tmux.conf:

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
set -ga terminal-overrides ",*256col*:Tc"
```

vimrc

```
set term=xterm-256color
```

Comment: After a long search, this was the option that worked for me. I didn't set the vimrc part though. Just the tmux.conf you pasted made it work on my side. Thanks!

Comment: I was having the same problem - using the KDE Konsole on Pop_OS Linux. I tried several options - but the combination of the two lines of code above for my tmux config solved it for me. I also omitted the line for vimrc - since I have mine configured for `termguicolors`.

Comment: This did the trick for me as well. for LazyVim/neovim+ tmux. In particular I only had the 2nd line on tmux.conf

Comment: thanks for your solution after spending lots of time on internet