# After installing lazyvim, neovim only shows the current line number

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

After installing lazyvim, my neovim only shows the current line number.

How do I show all line numbers?

I typed ':set number' but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your question you've posted your `.bashrc` file, this is not the file which contains `LazyVim` configuration. First you need to ensure that the number option is set to `true` in your `LazyVim` configuration files. you can add these 2 line in your `options.lua` file or `vim-options.lua` for numbers and relative numbers.

```lua
opt.number = true 
opt.relativenumber = true
```

**or**

```lua
vim.cmd("set number")
vim.cmd("set relativenumber")
```

If you've already tried `:set number` and it didn't work, its possible that your configuration is being overridden somewhere else, or there's an issue with how `LazyVim` is loading your configuration. you should ensure that your `options.lua` or `vim-options.lua` file is correctly placed in your nvim configuration directory.

Comment: That captured image was used to demonstrate my problem. The image only shows line number 34. I ran it in a tmux environment, and confirmed that it was displayed normally if tmux was not used. I was able to solve the problem through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158508/lose-vim-colorscheme-in-tmux-mode.